# Тревоги на множестве комментариев

Tags: обсуждение, тревоги

Имеем некорректного содержания пост и кучу бессмысленных флуд-комментариев под ним.

Нормально ли использовать эту ситуацию для фарма "полезных тревог", или стоит отметить тревогой только пост? Только пост и один комментарий?

[image]

---

Встречал в справке рекомендацию:

> Если в сообщении много комментариев, которые должны быть удалены,
>   особенно если дискуссия продолжается, не нужно отмечать каждый
>   комментарий. Отметьте тревогой сообщение, привлекая внимания
>   модератора, и в строке «другое» объясните причину.
>   [Источник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging)

Является ли это рекомендацией или правилом? Предусмотрены ли какие-либо меры наказания за злоупотребление подобного рода?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Встречал в справке рекомендацию:

> Является ли это рекомендацией или правилом?

Кажется, Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос :)

Я думаю, если соблюдать меру, то всё должно быть нормально. Но самое худшее, что может случиться - личное сообщение от модератора, что стоит придерживаться упомянутых рекомендаций. Так как по сути - множественные тревоги в данном случае только лишь увеличивают количество работы модератора.

Не думаю, что кто-то в здравом уме и уже знакомый с подобной рекомендацией будет продолжать активно плодить тревоги, лишь бы заработать знак [Участковый](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/70/deputy) или [Прокурор](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/76/marshal).